# Archlinux failed to boot: can't access tty: job control turned off

Tags: arch-linux, linux-kernel, grub, pacman

I came across the problem after upgrading my system through `pacman -Syu`.

During the upgrade, I encountered a python package conflict which caused the upgrade transaction aborted. So I resolved the conflict: removing the python package by `pip uninstall pkg_name`, then retried `pacman -Syu`. This time no more errors.

Then I rebooted my system and the problem occurred:

```
Warning: /lib/modules/4.19.1-arch1-1-ARCH/modules.devname not found - ignoring
starting version 239
/dev/nvme0n1p2: clean, 968023/31227904 files, 27066236/124895569 blocks
mount: /new_root: unknown filesystem type 'ext4'
You are now being dropped into an emergency shell,
sh: can't access tty: job control turned off
[rootfs] #
```

BTW: As the warning indicating, I was upgrading kernel 4.18 to 4.19

Comment: Edit your question with the output of `pacman -Q linux && uname -r`.

Comment: @jasonwryan Sorry I can't make it. Since the last reboot, I can no longer login in my system, blocked by the `Warning` posted above. However I do remember that before the last reboot I executed `uname -r` and the ouput kernel version was still 4.18.xxx

Comment: You need to chroot in, make sure `/` and `/boot` are mounted and then reinstall linux.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If the update was aborted and the kernel was in the process of being updated, you probably still have the initramfs of the the old kernel in your `/boot` whilst having the new kernel installed which can prevent booting. This can also happen on a freshly installed system if you forgot to properly mount the `/boot` partition.

The easiest way to fix this would be to boot with an archlinux installation media, perform a `chroot` and reinstall the kernel using `pacman`

```
# mount /dev/yourrootdisk /mnt
# mount /dev/yourbootdisk /mnt/boot # if needed
# mount /dev/yourefipartition /mnt/boot/EFI # if you use EFI (optionnal)
# arch-chroot /mnt
# pacman -S linux
```

The files that should be modified are `/boot/initramfs-linux.img` and `/boot/initramfs-linux-fallback.img` so you probably don't need to mount the EFI partition

If for some reason you can't use `pacman`, you can also launch `mkinitcpio` by hand to regenerate the initramfs to use the new kernel

Comment: Your answer is correct, but please do *not* advise people to `-Sy $package`, it is terrible advice and just leads [to breakage](https://gist.github.com/vodik/5660494).

Comment: indeed good point, edited

Comment: @Fredszaq Many thanks for your answer, it saved me from serious trouble. Still, I don't quite understand what went wrong in my case, as the command `pacman -Syu` ran with no conflicts before I could not boot. Maybe there is something wrong with my setup. If you can, would you please check out my pacman.log and tell me if I'm missing something? link to file in case you can: ix.io/2s1w

Answer (score 0):

The text `can't access tty: job control turned off` is just a notification by the shell that job control doesn't work, that means that you can't stop a program with <kbd>Ctrl+C</kbd> or  <kbd>Ctrl+Z</kbd>.

The problem is visible in the lines above, and maybe what is above that lines:

```
Warning: /lib/modules/4.19.1-arch1-1-ARCH/modules.devname not found - ignoring
mount: /new_root: unknown filesystem type 'ext4'
```

It seems the kernel modules are not found, and therefor no module `ext4`, and therefor no mounting the `ext4` root file system.

Most distributions don't delete the old kernel in case there is something wrong with the new one, so try to boot the previous kernel.

If that doesn't work, boot a live system and either install the previous kernel with matching modules, or the new one, or any kernel that works.

It's also possible that there was just something wrong with the creation of the initrd file system, that `ext4` was not included for some reasons. In this case, you can boot a live system, recreate initrd with `ext4` and reboot.

Comment: Arch *does* remove the old kernel. OP's issue is that /boot wasn't mounted during that upgrade so the installed modules do not match the kernel.

Comment: @jasonwryan If /boot was not mounted, then the matching kernel and initrd should be in the root file system, so it should be possible to load them from there.

Comment: Not necessarily; actual /boot may get mounted over the top or the initrd could be corrupted. The only safe approach is to chroot and fix it.

Answer (score 0):

command below free me,

```
mdev -s
```

my qemu command is

```
qemu-system-x86_64 \
    -s \
    -kernel bzImage \
    -initrd initrd.img.gz \
    -smp 4 \
    -m 1024 \
    -append "console=ttyS0 root=/dev/ram " \
    -monitor vc -serial stdio \
    -nographic
```

and I add `mdev -s`  in my `/init` file.

I hope it helps.