# Why am I being thrown into an emergency shell when booting?

Tags: arch-linux, systemd, boot, lvm

I have set up [Arch Linux with full-disk encryption](https://l0b0.wordpress.com/2016/10/07/full-disk-encryption-with-arch-linux-footnotes/) and partitioned my system disk using LVM. I just changed the motherboard, CPU and RAM of my machine, and after enabling legacy boot and disabling secure boot it booted fine at least once — I was asked for the LUKS passphrase, the GRUB menu showed up, lightdm and Awesome WM started fine, and I used the system for some hours. I then started Windows 7 and established that it refuses to work with current gen hardware. It may have messed with things in the process. Next time I booted the LUKS prompt showed up, I got the GRUB menu, and selected Arch Linux, but shortly afterwards my screen looked like this:

```
Starting version 241.7-2-arch
ERROR: device '/dev/mapper/vg-root' not found. Skipping fsck.
mount: /new_root: no filesystem type specified.
You are now being dropped into an emergency shell.
sh: can't access tty: job control turned off
[rootfs ]#
```

The *really* weird thing is that /dev/mapper/vg-root clearly does exist: I was able to mount it, mount my home directory within it, chroot to it and see all my files, and finally when I ran `reboot` outside the chroot it took me straight to the lightdm login screen. Why `reboot` would *continue* the boot rather than restart the machine is beyond me, but might just be a red herring.

What is going on here? Is there some known issue with this version of systemd?

I verified that the UUID of the root disk has not changed.

Comment: This is probably the same as https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/481857/5132 .

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Archlinux failed to boot: can't access tty: job control turned off](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/481857/archlinux-failed-to-boot-cant-access-tty-job-control-turned-off)