# can't access tty; job control turned off

Tags: arch-linux, boot, boot-loader, manjaro

I was doing some application updates and suddenly the PC crushed. After I relogged Im getting this:

[image]

Also on this screen i cant type anything with the keyboard.

I read some other similar threads like [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/481857/archlinux-failed-to-boot-cant-access-tty-job-control-turned-off) but I dont have extended linux knowledge and I dont know if the issue is the same so I dont wanna do the things worse. I would appreciate any help.

UPDATE:

I chroot inside the partition and tried to follow the link above:

```
[manjaro-gnome /]# uname -r

5.3.11-1-MANJARO

[manjaro-gnome /]# pacman -Q linux

linux414 4.14.155-1

[manjaro-gnome /]# mkinitcpio -P

==> ERROR: No presets found in /etc/mkinitcpio.d


[manjaro-gnome /]# grub-mkconfig -o boot/grub/grub.cfg
Generating grub configuration file ...
Found background: /usr/share/grub/background.png
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.19-x86_64
Found initrd image: /boot/intel-ucode.img /boot/initramfs-4.19-x86_64.img
Found initrd fallback image: /boot/initramfs-4.19-x86_64-fallback.img
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.14-x86_64
Found initrd image: /boot/intel-ucode.img /boot/initramfs-4.14-x86_64.img
Found initrd fallback image: /boot/initramfs-4.14-x86_64-fallback.img
grub-probe: error: cannot find a GRUB drive for /dev/sdd1.  Check your device.map.
grub-probe: error: cannot find a GRUB drive for /dev/sdd1.  Check your device.map.
Found memtest86+ image: /boot/memtest86+/memtest.bin
done
```

Comment: crush - relog (not reboot?). There is a "hibernation" problem, which amounts to a reboot problem. Looks like "it" hibernated without being configured. Quite realted to the link you found: the "job control off" is only the symptom.

Comment: your shell is running on `/dev/console` which doesn't support job control (it cannot be made the controlling tty of the session). If you want to be able to ^Z, fg, etc in that emergency shell, run `script -q /dev/null`. But the problem is that your system cannot find its root -- not the ease of use of that emergency shell ;-)

Comment: I wanted to say reboot not relog. @mosvy I cant use the keyboard at this screen!

Comment: sorry, I didn't notice that. Try booting from a install/live CD, and then mount your system from there, chroot into it, and try to repair it. Anyways, that "job control turned off" doesn't offer any clue as to what went wrong.

Comment: See also https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/481857/5132 and https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/507097/5132 .